# How to dynamically update members that depend on other members?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++17

Suppose I have a class `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass{
    private:
        vector<vector<float>> _vec;
    public:
        MyClass(vector<vector<float>> arg){
            _vec = arg;
            // shape is a 2-element vector where shape[0] = #elems in _vec 
            // and shape[1] = #elems in _vec[0]
            shape.push_back(_vec.size());
            shape.push_back(_vec.begin()->size());
        }
        vector<int> shape;
};
```

Now suppose I have a member function `func` of MyClass:

```
MyClass MyClass::func(){
    MyClass res(this->_vec);
    // delete the first element of `res._vec` 
    res._vec.erase(res._vec.begin());
    return res;
}
```

Now, if I do:

```
MyClass A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; // A.shape[0] = 2, A.shape[1] = 2
MyClass B = A.func(); // B._vec is {{3, 4}} but B.shape[0] is still 2
```

Here, `B._vec` changes, but `B.shape` is not "updated" accordingly.

How can I dynamically update `MyClass.shape` as and when `MyClass._vec` changes? One way to do this is to instead make a member function `MyClass.shape()` which whenever called checks the current `MyClass._vec`. But is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why aren't you updating `res.shape` in `func`?

Comment: @StephenNewell I think the question is "how to update `shape` without updating it in every function that modifies `vec`?"

Comment: if the members `_vec` and `shape` are related via an invariant then your design is fundamentally broken. Anybody can modify `shape` because it is `public`

Comment: btw your constructor invokes undefined behavior when `arg` is empty. You should check if `_vec.begin()` is a valid iterator before dereferencing it

Comment: Making `shape` a member function instead of a member variable would be my recommended way of doing it. That will mean that calling code can't modify `shape` independently of the underlying vector. (I would suggest making it return something like a `std::pair` instead of a vector, because if you know it's supposed to be returning exactly two elements, you might as well commit that to the interface.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I dynamically update MyClass.shape as and when MyClass._vec changes?

Write a function that updates `shape`, and call it whenever you change `_vec`.

> But is there a better way of doing this?

Don't use `shape` member at all, but instead call `_vec.size()` and `_vec.begin()->size()` when you need those values. This way there is nothing to update, no redundant duplicate waste of memory, and the user of the class cannot break the apparently missing invariant.

Comment: Or, if you think `_vec.size()` and `_vec.begin()->size()` are at too low a level of abstraction for calling code, write accessors in MyClass. e.g. `int MyClass::width() const { return _vec.size(); }`